# React forms - defaultValue not rendering text, but placeholder and value both work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, default-value

I'm having an issue with my react input fields, where I'm trying to render a defaultValue property. With defaultValue, nothing shows up in the field, but using placeholder or value both work fine.

However, neither placeholder nor value implement the functionality I'm looking for... I need defaultValue. Below is a mockup thats similar to what I'm doing. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
import React from 'react'

const EditingPost = props => {
  const index = props.match.params.post
  const post = props.posts[index]
  return(
    <div>
      <form id="edit-label-post">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title" autoFocus
          defaultValue={post.title}/>
        <textarea
          id="content"
          defaultValue={post.content}>
        </textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EditingPost
```

Comment: What's `post` here? It has no value in the code you posted.

Comment: maybe try defaultValue={index.title} ?

Comment: edited* i scooped out a lot of the component's code which is irrelevant to this particular issue, my declaration for 'post' accidentally went with it!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it index.title and index.content ? Or there needs to be more info I think...

Comment: edited* i scooped out a lot of the component's code which is irrelevant to this particular issue, my declaration for 'post' accidentally went with it!